# Adding data-pos info to latex output

Tags: lua, pandoc

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74172450/2554330), Pandoc records Synctex-like information when the source is `commonmark+sourcepos`.  For example, with this commonmark input,

```
---
title: "Sample"
---

This is a sample document.
```

the output in native format starts like this:

```
Pandoc
  Meta
    { unMeta =
        fromList [ ( "title" , MetaInlines [ Str "Sample" ] ) ]
    }
  [ Div
      ( "" , [] , [ ( "data-pos" , "Sample.knit.md@5:1-6:1" ) ] )
      [ Para
          [ Span
              ( ""
              , []
              , [ ( "data-pos" , "Sample.knit.md@5:1-5:5" ) ]
              )
              [ Str "This" ]
          , Span
              ( ""
              , []
              , [ ( "data-pos" , "Sample.knit.md@5:5-5:6" ) ]
              )
              [ Space ]
          , Span
              ( ""
              , []
              , [ ( "data-pos" , "Sample.knit.md@5:6-5:8" ) ]
              )
              [ Str "is" ]
```

but all that appears in the .tex file is this:

```
{This}{ }{is}...
```

As a step towards Synctex support, I'd like to insert the data-pos information as LaTeX markup, i.e. change the .tex output to look like this:

```
{This\datapos{Sample.knit.md@5:1-5:5}}{ \datapos{Sample.knit.md@5:5-5:6}}{is\datapos{Sample.knit.md@5:6-5:8}}...
```

This looks like something a Lua filter could accomplish pretty easily:  look for the `data-pos` records, copy the location information into the `Str` record.  However, I don't know Lua or Pandoc native language.  Could someone help with this?  Doing it for the `Span` records would be enough for my purposes.  I'm using Pandoc 2.18 and Lua 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt that appears to work.  Comments or corrections would still be welcome!

```lua
Span = function(span)
  local datapos = span.attributes['data-pos']
  if datapos then
    table.insert(span.content, pandoc.RawInline('tex', "\\datapos{" .. datapos .. "}"))
  end
  return span
end
```

Comment: As the author of pandoc Lua filters, this is *exactly* how I would do it. (OK, maybe I'd use method syntax`span.content:insert(pandoc.RawInline(...))`, but that's just taste.)

Comment: @tarleb:  Thanks for the confirmation, and thanks for making Lua filters available!